# How to get a Image in client.wait_for function in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make a avatar changer in discord.py and i need to download the image to set it as the avatar, But i dont know how to get the image in client.wait_for.

I havent really tried alot except

```
def check(m):
    return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
  message_1 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
  message = message_1.content
```

So please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the `message_1` contains any attachments, and if so, if the `content_type` of the first attachment is an image, like so:

```py
def check(m):
    return m.author.id == ctx.author.id

message_1 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)

if message_1.attachments:
    if m.attachments[0].content_type.startswith("image"):
        print("yes")
        # do whatever here
```

Or what you could also do is add these if statements to your `check` directly:

```py
def check(m):
    return (
        m.author.id == ctx.author.id
        and m.attachments
        and m.attachments[0].content_type.startswith("image")
    )

message_1 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)

print("yes")
# do whatever here
```

Comment: So it kinda worked but when i tried to change the avatar using `await client.user.edit(avatar=message_1.attachments[0])` it gave me this error `AttributeError: 'Attachment' object has no attribute 'startswith'`